# HTML5/CSS3 - Float issue

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a "posts__box" ("Davi Jesus" section) that is floating far to the right even with a "posts__box--left" class ("float: left"). HTML is fine, CSS is fine, I'm freaking out 'cause I can't understand why the heck this is happening.

btw: "revista" means "magazine" and it's my first time trying to apply BEM methodoly. I'm a newbie webdesigner.

Images:[image: Davi Jesus posts__box]

```css
.posts {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  height: 1400px;
  margin: 0 135px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.box--btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px dimgray;
}

.posts__box {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 30%;
}

.box--title {
  text-align: center;
}

.box--img {
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px Dimgray;
}

.box--text {
  padding: 5px;
}

.box--author {
  float: right;
  width: 46%;
  height: 50px;
}

.box--author--text {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.box--continue {
  float: left;
  width: 46%;
  height: 50px;
}

.box--continue--text {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}

.posts__btns {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}


/* MODIFIERS */

.revista__posts--height {
  height: 3000px;
}


/* posts */

.title--red {
  color: rgba(233, 26, 26, 1);
}

.title--size-small {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px black;
}

.title--size-large {
  font-size: 60px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px black;
}

.box--btn--red {
  background: rgba(233, 26, 26, 1);
}

.continue--white {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px black;
}

.box--btn--black {
  background: #212121;
}

.author--white {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}

.posts__box--left {
  float: left;
}

.posts__box--right {
  float: right;
}

.posts__box--margin--fix--left {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.posts__box--margin--fix--top {
  margin-top: 34px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.posts__btns--left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.posts__btns--right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}


/* revista */

.container__border {
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  border-left: 4px solid black;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
}

.revista__container--height {
  height: 4800px;
}
```

```html
<article class="posts">

  <section class="container revista__container--height container__border">

    <!-- davi jesus -->
    <section class="posts__box posts__box--left">

      <div class="box--title">
        <a class="title--red --hover" href="..\revista\artistas\davi-jesus.html">
         <h1 class="title--size-small --hover--darkred">Davi de Jesus do Nascimento:<br> corpo de rio</h1>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div>
       <a href="..\revista\artistas\davi-jesus.html">
         <img class="box--img" src="..\_img\posts\davi-de-jesus\instax\6.png" alt="">
       </a>
      </div>

  <div class="box--continue box--btn box--btn--red">
    <a class="--hover" href="..\revista\artistas\davi-jesus.html">
      <h5 class="box--continue--text continue--white -font--very-small --hover--dimgray">CONTINUAR A LEITURA</h5>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="box--author box--btn box--btn--black">
   <a class="--hover" href="..\revista\artistas\daniel-jesus.html">
     <h2 class="box--author--text author--white -font--small --hover--dimgray">Davi Jesus</h2>
   </a>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: I close my editor now and I'm going to sleep but I think I should post the container classes too? I checked it and it look like it was ok, I mean the other "posts__box" section are behaving fine (as you can see by author and continue btns above "davi jesus" post) even with some margin issues mainly in it's child elements wich I'm fixing with some clumpsy margin classes.

Comment: It is probably because of the parent of <section> could you add the complete code

Comment: fixed @MrcRjs (: 

Sorry about tidy code. It was 3am and I was sleepy.

Comment: The code that you have posted does not recreate the layout in your image.

Comment: Sure. To recreate the layout in my img I would have to post a lot more code that wouldn't make it minimal and clean.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it with a simple "clear: left" class. I guess it was just some weird bug or something like that. If someone has a different explanation and could share with us, I would appreciate. Thanks!